# Make Child Div Float Right of Parent

Tags: css

I'd like to make an inner div float right of the parent, **regardless of the width of the parent**.  An example of what this looks like is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eqDyy/.  That fiddle is just an example of what it should look like.  It's done with the exact number of pixels given, but what I'm looking for is a solution that still lets that inner div appear to the right of its parent, even when the parent width changes.

The following is the code used in the fiddle:

HTML

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#one {
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
}
#two {
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-top:-2px;
}
```

Again, please remember that this is just to show what I'd like it to look like, but it isn't a satisfying implementation because it uses specific pixel amounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since percentage-based margins are calculated against the containing block's width, you can set `margin-left` to `100%`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eqDyy/1/)

Comment: Wow, that's so ridiculously simple... I feel bad now for not thinking of that myself. Thanks!  I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#one {
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
}
#two {
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    width:50px;
    height:30px;
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-top:-2px;
    float:right;
}
```

I changed #two a little to show you the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/eqDyy/3/

Comment: That seems to make the inner div float right inside of the parent.  I was looking to have the inner div float right of the parent.  Freejosh's answer does that:  `margin-left:100%`

Comment: @SamuelReid I would have gone the float right route as it allows you to put content into the divs without the alignment going out of whack: [float right example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/eqDyy/4/) vs [margin-left](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/eqDyy/5/)

Comment: I'm using this for a drop down menu, similar to what you might find in something like son of suckerfish, but suckerfish's menu items have a fixed width, and my menus require a variable width.  The `margin-left:100%` is so I can put submenus out to the right of their respective parent element.

Comment: shouldn't you be absolutely positioning them then?